# Count and group the number of times each town is listed in the table

Tags: sql, oracle-apex

```
SELECT PEOPLE.TOWNKEY, TOWN_LOOKUP.TOWN FROM PEOPLE
INNER JOIN TOWN_LOOKUP
ON PEOPLE.TOWNKEY = TOWN_LOOKUP.PK
 ORDER BY TOWN
```

Current Table Output:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's rather unclear what you ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the `group by` clause entirely:

```
SELECT     tl.town, COUNT(*)
FROM       people p
INNER JOIN town_lookup ON p.townkey = tl.pk
GROUP BY   tl.town
ORDER BY   tl.town
```